# How to execute a jenkins declarative script from another declarative script?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want to execute nested declarative scripts that pre exist. Say I have this Declarative script in my workspace and its called test.DS

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    parallel {
      stage('stage-1') {
        steps {
            sh "echo this is stage-1"
        }
      }
      stage('stage-2') {
        steps {
            sh "echo this is stage-2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What would a declarative script look like that will run this script test.DS?

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the possible solutions

```
node {
         load './test.DS'
     }
```

Comment: Ram this is a scripted pipeline.  I interested in how to chain Declarative pipelines together.

Comment: the problem I'm running into is when i load the 2nd pipeline from a scripted pipeline it shows 
Only one pipeline { ... } block can be executed in a single run.

Comment: Should the first pipeline be declarative only ? Are there any reason for that strict requirement?

Comment: If a Declarative pipeline can be made to load another declarative pipeline as a conditional step, then you would not get the error that happens now with load... which is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one pipeline { ... } block can be executed in a single run.`  So I don't know how to call another Declarative pipeline.